# How to iterate through a set in a constraint?

Tags: python, constraints, abstract, pyomo

I would like to iterate through a set in a constraint. I have built an abstract model. Let's assume the following dictionaries for the instance:

```
dict_Nodes = {None: ['N1', 'N2']}
dict_Nodes_ArcsOut = {'N1': ['N1N4', 'N1N3'], 'N2': ['N2N5', 'N2N7']}
dict_Time = {None: [0, 1, 2]}
dict_Arcs = {None: ['N1N4', 'N1N3', 'N2N5', 'N2N7']}
```

However, as I am constructing an abstract model the data should not really matter.
I want to say that the variable in node N1 is the same value as in the arcs N1N4 and N1N3. For the abstract model I created several sets:

```
from pyomo.environ import AbstractModel, Param, minimize, Var, Constraint,\
    SolverFactory, Set, Objective, NonNegativeReals, Reals, Binary, ConstraintList

model = AbstractModel()

model.Set_Nodes = Set()
model.Set_Arcs = Set()
model.Set_Time = Set()
model.Set_Nodes_ArcsOut = Set(model.Set_Nodes)

model.Var_Arc = Var(model.Set_Arcs, model.Set_Time, within=NonNegativeReals)
model.Var_Node = Var(model.Set_Nodes, model.Set_Time, within=NonNegativeReals)
```

Looking at the data I would like to say that:

```
Var_Arc['N1N4'] = Var_Node['N1']
Var_Arc['N1N3'] = Var_Node['N1']
Var_Arc['N2N5'] = Var_Node['N2']
Var_Arc['N2N7'] = Var_Node['N2']
```

To implement the constraint I tried the following two options:

```
def Arc_rule(model, node, t):
        for arc in model.Set_Nodes_ArcsOut[node]:
            return model.Var_Arc[arc, t] == model.Var_Node[node, t]
model.ArcInTemp_rule = Constraint(model.Set_Nodes, model.Set_Time, rule=ArcInTemp_rule)
```

This option only takes the first position of the list. This is probably caused by the return which stops the iteration.
Option 2:

```
def _init(model):
   for t in model.Set_Time:
      for node in model.Set_Nodes_ArcsOut:
          yield model.Var_Arcs_TempIn[model.Set_Nodes_ArcsOut[node], t] == model.Var_Nodes_TempMix[node, t]
model.init_conditions = ConstraintList(rule=_init)
```

This does not work and I get the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: '_InsertionOrderSetData'.
I do not understand because I can do this operation if I do a summation. However, iteration seems to be impossible with an abstract model.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It's not at all clear which sets are ``dict``s, ``set``s, or ``Set``s, and how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are getting "bound up" here because you have the same data in your model twice with 2 formats.  The data in "arcs" and "nodes_arcsout" is redundant...  If you know one, you know the other.  Can you get rid of one of them?  And then reformat the other...  arcs should be something like {(N1, N4), (N1, N2), ...} or if you went the other way, it should be {N1: [N4, N3], N2: ... }

Comment: But it could also happen that N1 is corresponding to ten elements and not only two. Could you maybe do a suggestion to your proposal, because I do not fully get your point? It is basically a simple grid Problem and I want the variable value of the leaving arcs to be the same value as the node that they leave. I am open to a reformulation. An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rephrased the problem and illustrated it based on the pyomo example. The tryRule is what I needed:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.AbstractModel()

model.Nodes = pyo.Set()
model.Arcs = pyo.Set(dimen=2)

def NodesOut_init(m, node):
    for i, j in m.Arcs:
        if i == node:
            yield j
model.NodesOut = pyo.Set(model.Nodes, initialize=NodesOut_init)

def NodesIn_init(m, node):
    for i, j in m.Arcs:
        if j == node:
            yield i
model.NodesIn = pyo.Set(model.Nodes, initialize=NodesIn_init)

model.Flow = pyo.Var(model.Arcs, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.NodeFlow = pyo.Var(model.Nodes, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.FlowCost = pyo.Param(model.Arcs)

model.Demand = pyo.Param(model.Nodes)
model.Supply = pyo.Param(model.Nodes)

def Obj_rule(m):
    return pyo.summation(m.FlowCost, m.Flow)
model.Obj = pyo.Objective(rule=Obj_rule, sense=pyo.minimize)

def tryRule(m, i, j):
    return m.Flow[i, j] == m.NodeFlow[i]
model.tryRule = pyo.Constraint(model.Arcs, rule=tryRule)

def FlowBalance_rule(m, node):
    return m.Supply[node] \
        + sum(m.Flow[i, node] for i in m.NodesIn[node]) \
        - m.Demand[node] \
        - sum(m.Flow[node, j] for j in m.NodesOut[node]) \
        == 0
model.FlowBalance = pyo.Constraint(model.Nodes, rule=FlowBalance_rule)

dict_data = {
    None: {
        'Nodes': {None: ['CityA', 'CityB', 'CityC']},
        'Arcs': {None: [('CityA', 'CityB'), ('CityA', 'CityC'), ('CityC', 'CityB')]},
        'FlowCost': {
            ('CityA', 'CityB'): 1.4,
            ('CityA', 'CityC'): 2.7,
            ('CityC', 'CityB'): 1.6,
        },
        'Demand': {
            'CityA': 0,
            'CityB': 1,
            'CityC': 1,
        },
        'Supply': {
            'CityA': 2,
            'CityB': 0,
            'CityC': 0,
        }
    }
}

# create instance
instance = model.create_instance(dict_data)
instance.pprint()
```

The result for the rule is:

```
tryRule : Size=3, Index=Arcs, Active=True
        Key                : Lower : Body                                : Upper : Active
        ('CityA', 'CityB') :   0.0 : Flow[CityA,CityB] - NodeFlow[CityA] :   0.0 :   True
        ('CityA', 'CityC') :   0.0 : Flow[CityA,CityC] - NodeFlow[CityA] :   0.0 :   True
        ('CityC', 'CityB') :   0.0 : Flow[CityC,CityB] - NodeFlow[CityC] :   0.0 :   True
```